# strings from DynamoDB that were originally byte arrays have funky values

Tags: c#, encryption, amazon-dynamodb, ripemd

Now I'm not sure if this is something I'm doing wrong, or something thats happening in DynamoDB..

Basically, Im building a simple registration/login system for my project, saving the userdata/password in a DynamoDB instance with the password hashed using RIPEMD160, and salted as well using C#'s `RNGCryptoServiceProvider()`.

Registration seems to work perfectly fine. the issue is upon login, no matter what, the passwords dont match up, and I think its because I'm getting some funky characters back when pulling the hash/salt back from DynamoDB. First off, both the hash and the salt are byte arrays of length 20, and converted to strings before saved in the database.

These examples are copy/pasted from the dynamo web interface

```
Example Hash: ">�Bb.ŧ�E���d��Ʀ"  
Example Salt: "`���!�!�Hb�m�}e�"
```

When they're coming back and I debug into the function that pulls back the data from dynamo, both strings have different characters (VS2010 Debugger):

```
Returned Hash: "u001B>�Bb.ŧ�E��u0003�d�u001C�Ʀ"  
Returned Salt: "`���!u000B�!�Hb�u001Dmu0012�u0001}e�"
```

Seems these u001B, u000B, u001D, u0012, u0003, u001C, and u0001 are sneaking into the returned data, and I'm not entirely sure whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to convert opaque binary data into a string in this way in the first place. They're *not text* so don't treat them that way. You're just begging to lose information that way.

Use `Convert.ToBase64String(data)` instead of `Encoding.GetString` before putting the data into the database. When you get it out again, use `Convert.FromBase64String` to retrieve the original binary data.

Alternatively, don't store the data in a text field to start with - use a database field type which is *meant* to store binary data...

Comment: Regarding last note, Amazon's DynamoDB has text/number/sets of those attributes only. he didn't have a choice.

Comment: Using convert to turn the raw data into a Base64 string and then storing it in a dynamo row as a string and then using convert to turn it back is a fine workaround for the fact that dynamo doesn't support a binary datatype.